# How to check a specific kubernetes pod is up or not in Grafana metrics

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I am creating a grafana dashboard to show metrices. 
Is there any keyword which i can use in my query to check my service is running or not.
I am using prometheus to retrive data from my api for the metrics creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query like so

```
count_scalar(container_last_seen{name=<container_name>})
```

That will give you the count of how many containers are running with that name